# How to use Subclass of UIPageViewController in XIB (Interface Builder) to set DataSource, Delegate and TransitionStyle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, xib

How can I use a subclass of UIPageViewController in a XIB file to set DataSource, Delegate and TransitionStyle?

The attrubute inspector is empty if i set PageViewController as the class of File's Owner.
Even if i set UIPageViewController as class of File's Owner i cannot set the attributes.

[image: XCode 5 Printscreen]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could help you, passing your custom class it should works

[image]

Comment: that is what i have already done, and i tried to explain that issue. i clearyfied this in adding a printscreen.

Comment: @Sam sorry, i haven't seen

Answer (score -1):

Do it in storyboard. You will be able add in it UIPageViewController and specify in it yours subclass.

**EDIT:**

If you doesn't wish use storyboard, than:

1. create empty xib
2. plase inside it pageviewcontroller
3. specify yours UIPageViewController subclass name.
4. load as:

   ```
   MyPageViewController* mpv = (MyPageViewController*)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:...].lastObject;
   ```

Comment: That doesn't anwer my question. I want to use XIB and no story board.

Comment: @Sam, you can use storyboard for single viewcontroller. Why you need only XIB?